# Solution of $x^x = (x-1)^{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, tetration

Is there any way to solve this equation algebraically and give an exact form of the solution: $x^x = (x-1)^{x+1}$? WolframAlpha only finds the approximate solution 4.14.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463603/solve-for-x-in-ax-xb?noredirect=1    maybe helps

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A100086.

Comment: This is the [Foias constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoiasConstant.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \frac{(x-1)^{x+1}}{x^x}, \quad x > 1$$
and its logarithm
$$g(x) = \log f(x) = (x+1) \log (x-1) - x \log x, \quad x > 1.$$
The original equality is satisfied whenever $g = 0$.  A plot of $g$ is shown as follows:
[image]
We can compute successive iterates of the Newton's method recursion of $g$ with an initial guess of $x_0 = 4$:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{2x_n - (x_n - 1) \log (x_n - 1)}{2 + (x_n - 1)\log(1 - 1/x_n)}$$

gives
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & x_n \\
0 & 4.00000000000000 \\
1 & 4.13751482760659 \\
2 & 4.14103935294361 \\
3 & 4.14104152540996 \\
4 & 4.14104152541079 \\
5 & 4.14104152541079
\end{array}$$

When $x < 1$, we run into problems with defining a real-valued function for $(x-1)^{x+1}$, which is why the domain is restricted.